# How to include third-party javascript nodejs library in cordova plugin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, bluebird

I'm developing a Cordova plugin for an internal project and would like to include a third-party open source Javascript library as part of my plugin: the bluebird promise library.

The simplest solution, it seems, would be to merely copy and paste the bluebird JS files into my `www/` directory and then include them all in my `plugin.xml` file in `<js-module>` tags so that they are copied into my plugin's directory. But I don't think that's what I want, because it very tightly couples my plugin to the structure of the bluebird library's files.

Moreover, I don't know if that would work in such a way that I could simply do `var Promise = require('bluebird');` in my own plugin's JS files.

I'm still new to how Cordova works, so I don't know what the best way forward is. I know that I want to be able to use that above `require` call to include bluebird where I need it, and I want to do it in a way that follows best practices for both Cordova's toolchain and the common way that things are done in JS these days; e.g., using npm, gulp, and/or grunt to package correctly bluebird into my plugin.

Thanks in advance for any pointers you may have.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bundler. Any of these will do:

- [webpack](https://webpack.js.org)
- [Browserify](http://browserify.org)
- [JSPM](http://jspm.io)

Then bundle your JS and ship the bundle with your plugin.

As far as promises are concerned, however, according to [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=Promise), iOS 8+ and Android 4.4.4+ support the Promise standard, as does Edge 12+. Depending on your supported platforms, you may not need to worry about an additional library (unless you're using bluebird-specific functionality).

Alternatively, you could allow the user to pass in their favorite promise library to a configuration method (as long as it meets the spec), and default to native Promises (or your installed bluebird library) if they don't override it.

Comment: Thanks,  I'll just use the native Promise standard, I don't need to worry about older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If your library is available in npm, which mostly likely it is, you can use the npm package: [`cordova-import-npm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-import-npm)